# Check wifi condition in Blackberry application

Tags: blackberry, wifi

I have developed an application for blackberry devices. The application is working fine if it uses internet via data service provider.

I have BB 9550 and I want to use my application using wifi. I tried a lot but I cant get proper answer to check wifi condition.

How we can differentiate to run our application for wifi or data service provider?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For checking wifi is connected or not the following method will help you.

```
 public static boolean isWifiConnected()
    {
        try
        {
            if (RadioInfo.getSignalLevel(RadioInfo.WAF_WLAN) != RadioInfo.LEVEL_NO_COVERAGE)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception during get WiFi status");
        }
        return false;
    }
```

if wifi is not connected the following methods will help to add data service.

```
public static String getConnParam(){
        String connectionParameters = "";
        if (WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED) {
        // Connected to a WiFi access point
        connectionParameters = ";interface=wifi";
        } else {
        int coverageStatus = CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus();
        ServiceRecord record = getWAP2ServiceRecord();
        if (record != null
        && (coverageStatus & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT) ==
        CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT) {
        // Have network coverage and a WAP 2.0 service book record
        connectionParameters = ";deviceside=true;ConnectionUID="
        + record.getUid();
        } else if ((coverageStatus & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) ==
        CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) {
        // Have an MDS service book and network coverage
        connectionParameters = ";deviceside=false";
        } else if ((coverageStatus & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT) ==
        CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT) {
        // Have network coverage but no WAP 2.0 service book record
        connectionParameters = ";deviceside=true";
        }

    }
        return connectionParameters;
    }
        private static  ServiceRecord getWAP2ServiceRecord() {
            ServiceBook sb = ServiceBook.getSB();
            ServiceRecord[] records = sb.getRecords();
            for(int i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
            String cid = records[i].getCid().toLowerCase();
            String uid = records[i].getUid().toLowerCase();

            if (cid.indexOf("wptcp") != -1 &&
            uid.indexOf("wifi") == -1 &&
            uid.indexOf("mms") == -1) {
            return records[i];
            }
            }
            return null;
            }
```

Example to use above methods.

```
String connParams=(isWifiConnected())?";interface=wifi":getConnParam();
```

Hope This will help you

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
private static String getParameters() {
    if (GetWiFiCoverageStatus()) {
        return ";deviceside=true;interface=wifi";
    }
    else {
        return yourParametersForEdge
    }
}

private static boolean GetWiFiCoverageStatus()  {
    if((WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED)) {
        return true;
    } 
    else 
        return false;           
}
```

And when you need to connect, you'll have to add the parameters to the URL:

```
yourUrl = yourUrl + getParameters();
```

Comment: Thaks your code your code also helpful for me to add parameter in url